# Get Previous/Next item by using PK

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

**views.py**

```
class ContentView(TemplateView):
    model = Content
    template_name = 'capt/pages/details.html'

    def get_context_data(self, pk, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['dataC'] = get_object_or_404(Content, title_id =self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        return context
```

so, I want to get the next object of my model:

```
class Section(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80, unique=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("media", kwargs={"pk":self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-pk"]
```

But I'm not familiar with CBV. I made dynamic urls by overriding the get_context_data but now idk how to get the next or previous object using the pk.

I thought using:

```
context['previtem'] = Content.objects.get(pk=self.pk-1)
```

would help me but I'm a lil bit stuck on this one.

Comment: It is not guaranteed to have an object with `pk-1`, say, if you have deleted some records.

Comment: sure, I understand that. But let's say that I have an empty database, I load some data and I don't delete it. I'd like to start there and then work on the validations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow!  An option here would be to sort the `Content` on some field like `name`.  From that sorted list, find the index `i` of the current instance, and then get the PK of instance `i-1`.  This is not a good answer if you have a potentially large list of things, but if you're just learning it is a good start.